# Laravel - Getting Html code through controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

I try to make some documentation page, with several pages.

(I'm using Laragon and virtual host, so URLs are like `mysite.dev/something`)

I created 2 routes :

```
Route::get('docs','DocsController@index');
Route::get('docs/{text}','DocsController@index');
```

So when I write URL `mysite.dev/docs`, I get kinda like a docs home page.

Here's the controller :

```
class DocsController extends Controller
{
    public function index($text = '', $f = '') {
        if ($text != '')
            if (Storage::has('testText/'.$text.'.html'))
                $f = Storage::get('testText/'.$text.'.html');
            else
                $f = 'File doesn\'t exist...';

        return view('docs')->with('text',$f);
    }
}
```

I tested it on some text files, and it work pretty good with Storage, but in this code, you can see '.html' because i tried to do the same thing with html files.
The result is the page containing the html code but written as text.

Is there a way to get this code from html files, and make it work as html ?
Maybe there is a better Facade than Storage to do this, but I don't know very well Laravel.

Comment: Your docs blade template probably needs {!! $text !!} where you have {{ $text }}. Many assumptions on this so could be wrong so not posted as an answer

Comment: I had {{ $text }} and I think this the safe way to make some input etc,
but {!! $text !!} actually take anything that it's given and display it correctly without doing anything.
That's actually work perfectly for my case, Thx :)

Comment: Yeah - that's what it does. Upgraded to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your docs blade template probably needs {!! $text !!} where you have {{ $text }}